# CakePHP 3 - Association not defined..?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to create a new many-to-many relationship in CakePHP 3 project.

I have the association defined, but somehow it still claims it is not... and i can't figure out why. I believe i have defined everything i need to, but it still claims the association is not created whenever i try to find something in the leftover table.

I have the following tables:

**leftovers**

**production_products**

So a "leftover" can have many production_products and vice-versa. So i make the following table classes:

**Leftovers.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->belongsToMany('ProductionProducts', [
        'through' => 'LeftoversProductionProducts'
    ]);
}
```

**LeftoversProductionProducts**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->belongsTo('Leftovers');
    $this->belongsTo('ProductionProducts');
}
```

**ProductionProductsTable**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $this->belongsToMany('Leftovers', [
        'through' => 'LeftoversProductionProducts'
    ]);
}
```

**Fetching the data**

```
$leftoversTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('leftovers');
    $leftover = $leftoversTable->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'production_products'
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: What's missing here is an example of the code where you're trying (and failing) to fetch some data using these associations.

Comment: ah yes, edited now.

Comment: You need to contain `ProductionProducts`, not `production_products`.